# In JavaScript, how do you determine the current event if not passed as arg?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In an arbitrary JavaScript function, I wish to determine the upstream event.

The event listener function did not pass the event do the current function.  As far as I know, `window.event` is *not* WC3 and not available.

```
function listener(e) { subfunc(e.target); }

function subfunc( element) {
    // here I wish to know which if any event responsible for me being called
    var event = ?;
    switch( event.type ) { ... }
}
```

How does function `subfunc()` determine the current event?

(Apologize if question asked before - seems it must have been - but cannot track it down.)

Comment: Your only chance is to pass `e` to `subfunc`, not only `e.target`. Or you set `window.event = e;` inside `listener`, but passing the event object seems to be a cleaner approach to me.

Comment: @Felix - on setting `window.event`, seems dangerous to try to maintain that state space.

Comment: @spender - wow!  seems like that would be a pretty useful thing to know.

Comment: @ccyoung: Agreed, that's why I said passing the event object is better :)

Comment: @Felix - right!  seems a choice between extra arg and `this`.  playing with code psychology now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
function listener(e) { subfunc.call(this, e); }

function subfunc( e ) {
    var element = this; //<- 'this' points to your element, 'e.type' is event type
    switch( e.type ) { ... }
}
```

Also other way:

```
function listener(e) { subfunc.call(e, e.target); }

function subfunc( element ) {
    var event = this; //<- 'this' points to your event object
    switch( event.type ) { ... }
}
```

Comment: good idea.  my problem is that `subfunc` can be waaaay deep in the stack, so each intervening function would also need to pass `this` or `e`.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. There's only one property which can be accessed through another, reliable way: `event.target` = `this` (Provided that the function is called from within the scope of the event listener).

The event object should be passed to `subfunc`.